# .Net framework on Mac

Tags: macos, .net-framework

Can I install .net framework on my apple laptop if I'm using Google Chrome?

I need to have .net framework for an accounting program called Sage 50, which isn't compatible with Mac.  So I had to download Chrome, and then when I try to enter Sage, it says I need .net framework.

I've looked but can't find .net for mac.  Does anybody know either where to find the program, or how to get around this?

Answer (score 3):

```
Can I install .NET framework on my apple laptop if I'm using Chrome?
```

The .NET Framework only supports the Windows operating system.

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) exists to support OS X and Linux.  Its an open source interoperation of the .NET Framework.

In order to use the accounting program in question you would need to use either a Windows Virtual Machine and/or boot into Windows directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simple solution is to get get a PC running windows.

Check out [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to go with this, you might want to check out Boot camp as a first option:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2JbvkdcfVY

If you don’t want to partition your Mac computer, you can use virtual machines. 
There are two large and widespread options here - WM Ware Fusion and Parallels. They are both 
commercial products, but there's also the free open-source alternative Virtual Box from Sun.

If you want to go free, look into the last option. (Works fine on Mac, PC and Linux) 
You can install all the operating systems you please and easily remove them again when you no longer need them. Virtual Box is not quite as streamlined as the other commercial versions. It’s an easy, free and painless solution that can be easily spooled back.

http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads